# Proving a criteria for a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ converging to a function non uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is an exercise from Michael Schramm's An Introduction to Real Analysis.

> Suppose $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions on $[0, 1]$ that converges
>   to a function $f$, but that the convergence is not uniform. Show that
>   there must be a sequence $(x_n)$ in $[0, 1]$ so that $x_n \to x \in [0,1]$ but $f(x_n)$
>   doesn't converge to $f(x)$.

---

Here's my attempt:

Suppose that$(f_n)$ converges to $f$ on $[0,1]$ but the convergence is not uniform. It follows by the definition that there is an $\varepsilon >0$ and  there is a sequence $(x_{k}) \in [0,1]$ and a subsequence of functions $(f_{n_k})$ such that $|f_{n_k}(x_{k})-f(x_{k})| \ge \varepsilon$.

By Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, let $(x_{m_k})$ be a subsequence converging to $x\in [0,1]$. I claim that $f(x_{m_k})$ cannot converge to $f(x)$.

---

This is as far as I was able to go. I tried using several inequalities to prove my claim but I was unsuccessful. Hints would be appreciated.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $f(x) = 0$, and:
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
x^n, &\text{if $x \in [0,1)$} \\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
$$
We have $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ pointwise, as $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x^n = 0$ $\forall x \in [0,1)$, but not uniformly as $\sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = 1$ $\forall n$. However, for any sequence $x_n \to x$ we must have $f(x_n) = 0 \to 0 = f(x)$.

Comment: How does the supremum = 1 show that it does not converge uniformly?

Comment: @SRobertJames Uniform convergence, by definition, means that $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since the supremum is constantly $1$, it does not converge to $0$.